# Error strange line between navigation list and fragment DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

This strange line appears in my view and don't know the reason

[image]

Edit 1: XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go on your XML file, take the DrawerLayout and cut it and put it on the tag before... so you will be able to see how it's designed.

So, put your `LinearLayout` of the DrawerLayout inside your visible view, edit it, and put it away again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, My Mistake. The shadow was causing this problem

mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow_rtl, GravityCompat.END);